# my website crashed ( joomla) on 1&1

Tags: database, joomla, crash

when i try to go on my website it have an error message :
"INSERT command denied to user 'XXXXXX'@'XXXXXX' for table '#__session' SQL=INSERT INTO `#__session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) VALUES ('e49d3a45bcccd80e0b2dcd4a43def7df', 0, '1378981803')"

www.ladycaprice.fr

I don't know what to do because i m not a programer, and my webmaster seems to have desapear... Could anyone help please ? 
Thanks a lot
EM

Comment: Don't put this info on stack. Let a programmer look at it. Delete this question before anyone abuses the info you just gave us.

Comment: I've edited it for the time being and flagged it for mod attention.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your database is full. Use the hosting control panel tools provided by your host (not the joomla backoffice, that you can't access right now) look for something like "Database administration" and see if there are any warnings.

If there are, then delete stuff from your DB. For that you *will* have to find your webmaster.

If he can access either a command-line administration shell, or directly on the DB server, then try entering

```
GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE ON joom2_session TO dbo330061515
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do NOT have the account/db passwords, contact your provider and have them sent to you. As the owner it's your right, and there is no way of solving this unless you gain access to the db administration.

#__session is where user sessions are stored. You can safely empty the table (easiest would be with phpmyadmin or another mysql manager, run the query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE jos_session
```

(replace `jos` with your actual database prefix).  If the table is broken, you need to run a repair).

If it starts working again see if you're not out of space on your account as @xaccrocheur mentioned.